# Error in XML Layout in android

Tags: android, xml

Error in below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center" android:background="@color/list_bg">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow>

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/t1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/t2" android:typeface="normal"
                android:singleLine="true" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t10" android:typeface="normal"
                android:singleLine="true" android:text=" " android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t4" android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="gone" android:singleLine="true" android:text="("
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t5" android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="gone" android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/t6" android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="gone" android:singleLine="true" android:text=")"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/t3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error is:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not 
     allowed.
    - No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the 
     document.

Please help...

Comment: First of all, which line is the error coming, is it the first? Try cleaning your project. Also are you getting this error while running or when typed in eclipse only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake there was a extra line before first line of my xml I have removed it and now its working fine.

Answer (score 4):

1)  Make sure you don't have any comment or white space or empty line before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

That declaration should be on top

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing any error when copied to my eclipse. Using Eclipse Juno and SDK 20, ADT version 20.0.1

Comment: There was an extra line before the first line of xml I found my mistake and resolved it. Thanks for the help...